# On some boots, I get a 0x0000003d BSOD

Tags: bsod, hardware-failure

Recently built a new rig with these specs:

- Asus p8z68-v pro
- Corsair Vengeance 1600Mhz 2x4GB
- i5 2500k

Now running at stock whenever I log in to windows 64bit it will run for a few minutes before blue screening, however I can manage to get a stable boot and have been able to play Crysis etc for several hours but then upon resetting the PC it will pull return to blue screening.

About 33% of the time, the BIOS will only register a single 4GB stick.
Every so often it will report that 'Overclocking failed.'
When I open Systems Information Windows it will report weird values such as 1.$, 1.$, and nonsensical timings 6--2147483648--2147483648--2147483648--2147483648 at 1.$ MHz, at 1.5 volts.
It will also after blue screening fail to recognize my SSD and request I insert boot media.

Is there a problem with the hardware configuration that I may not be aware of?

EDIT: Ran memtest for 2 hours without any errors.

Comment: Have you run memtest?

Comment: Woops forgot to mention that. Yeah I've run memtest for 2 hours on a stable boot and it reported no errors.

Comment: Try running it for longer. It seems to me (and this is not a certainty in any sense) that the common denominator between messed up error logs, a BSOD and a sometimes missing stick of RAM have a stick of RAM common. You might also try removing the faulty stick.

Comment: Are you sure the error is `0x00003d`? That is not enough numbers, and as is, stands for **Printer queue is full**.

Comment: sorry, it's a 0x0000003d error. missed a couple 0's

Comment: Keep in mind that memtest is only capable of returning a positive test result.  If memtest detects an error, you've got bad ram.  If memtest doesn't detect an error, you can't draw any conclusions about whether or not your ram is bad.  Generally when I have a machine exhibiting possible memory errors, I let memtest run for 24 hours or more before calling it quits.

Comment: It seems that the code is indicitive of a hardware or driver issue. see [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000003D.htm) for more

Comment: Well it’s still *Printer queue is full*, so something’s up. Is there [another code or filename or something](http://www.techrepublic.com/i/tr/downloads/images/bsod_a.jpg)? (Though to be honest, it sounds more like a hardware problem that software.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suspect the following, in order of probability:

- Issue with power or PSU
- Liquid damage on motherboard
- Check everything on motherboard to ensure it is connected properly and there are no loose screws or things that can short
- Bad RAM
- Bad graphics or other PCI card
- Update BIOS
- Bad hard drive or optical drive
- Update graphics driver

Answer (score 1):

Are you overclocking any hardware?

Not much on this bugcheck, it is a hardware interrupt issue.

> The INTERRUPT_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED bug check has a value of 0x0000003D.
>
> The following actions might prevent an error like this from happening again:
>
> Download and install updates and device drivers for your computer from Windows Update.
>
> Scan your computer for computer viruses.
>
> Check your hard disk for errors.

[Source of Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558963%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try running a CHKDSK scan in cmd:

CHKDSK checks for problems on the hard disk. There are three parameters that are relevant in this case: / f / r / x. This scan can take up to 5 hours, so you may not want to use this first.

• f – corrects errors that it finds

• r – restores bad sectors

• x – if necessary it dismounts the storage area first. All open handles to the drive are invalidated. /x also includes the functionality of /f

Open the Command Prompt (CMD) as administrator – click the windows start button and search for CMD. You will see the Command Prompt. Right-click on it and click run as administrator. CMD is short for Command Prompt.
Enter the command that you have chosen (in the image it is a SFC scan)
Wait for the process to finish and then restart your computer

[Source - How to fix error 0x0000003D](https://pcerrorcode.com/solved-fix-error-0x0000003d/)